# picture is pushed out of my javascript slideshow in Chrome, not in IE8

Tags: css

This is probably a simple problem, however I can't seem to find a solution that works in all browsers.

The link:
http://immeublesninamiller.com/fr/listings/details/?ID=71

The css where the problem I think is:

```
#image {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I have tried to use left:-250px; and it moves the IE8 picture to the left too, so that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust it to look right in Chrome first, then you can add additional lines of code with `*` in front of the rules so it only applies to IE such as: `*left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Add left:0 to your #image selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#image {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left:-250px;
}
```